# How can I customize the registration form in D7 Organic Groups?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am using Drupal 7 and Organic Groups 7.x-2.0-beta1. I have created a custom membership type to act as a custom registration form, but I can't seem to override the default membership type with the one I created.

I have one group type, but each group may have it's own registration form. I need the ability to load the custom registration form for each group. I'm assuming that with a custom module I could make this happen with Organic Groups' membership types.

I have added an Entity Reference to the membership types on the group content type, so I can access a specified membership type based on the group id.

Any idea of what function I could hook into to make a change? Any other ideas about how to implement a custom registration form for organic groups?

Comment: Have you ever tried combining organic groups and entity registration? (http://drupal.org/project/registration) That's what I'm currently trying, I think it would solve your problem as well.